# Starting a process from one terminal from another terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, process

I was wondering of there is any method to start a new process or a program from one terminal into other.

What I mean is: Let's say I have to run `gedit abc.txt`, but I don't want it to block my current terminal window.

Is there a way I can run [gedit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit) from one terminal into other terminal window? Or can I use gedit without blocking the current terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `gedit` as:

```
gedit file.txt &
```

The `&` at the end will cause the process to run in background and you will be able to use the current terminal interactively again.

Comment: It is the recommended solution +1

Comment: Problematic when the terminal is closed.

Comment: @A.B.: yes, but in this context this is all right as OP mentioned `without blocking current terminal`, which i think just mean that the Op can use terminal interactively again..

Comment: @heemayl Yes, alright, I just wanted to point out.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this command:

```
gedit abc.txt & disown
```

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disown_(Unix))

> In the bash shell, the disown builtin command is used to remove jobs from the job table, or to mark jobs so that a SIGHUP signal is not sent to them if the parent shell receives it (e.g. if the user logs out).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ability to run in background.

To do it just put & at the end of your command. for example:

```
$ gedit example.txt &

 [1] 12642
```

To list all processes in the background use the `job` command.

```
 $ jobs

[1]+  Running                 gedit example.txt &
```

To bring the process to foreground again use the `fg` command:

```
$ fg %1

gedit example.txt
```

where %1 represent the first process in the background. %x means the x process.